# Table inside table using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am new to `angularjs` and `web-development` .I am using ng-repeat to represent the data in a complicated table ,  like this :

```
A     B   C     D
abc  pqr  xyz   std
```

So,This is the code :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered report-table table-fixed" contextmenu-container="meta.contextmenu" fixed-header>
            <thead class="text-center text-info">
              <th class="text-center">A</th>
              <th class="text-center">B</th>
              <th class="text-center">C</th>
              <th class="text-center">D</th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="report in reports.data">
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.annotation }}</td>

              <td class="td-report-field" contenteditable="{{enableReportEditing}}" contextmenu-item="report" context-menu="menuOptions">{{ report.attributes.field }}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-if="report.attributes.message && showcheckbox" ng-bind="report.attributes.message" ng-click="getcheckedData(report.attributes.message)">
                <span ng-if="report.attributes.message" contentEditable ng-model="report.attributes.message">
                      {{ report.attributes.message }}
                    </span>
                <span ng-if="!report.attributes.message">{{ report.attributes.message }}</span>
              </td>
              <td class="text-center">{{ report.attributes.score }}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```

And the `json` is like :

```
{
        "type": "report",
        "id": 14,
        "attributes": {
            "annotation": "abc",
            "field": "pqr",
            "message": "xyz",
            "score": "7"
        },
        "innerAnnotations": {
            {
                "annotation": "jkl",
                "field": "pqr",
                "message": "xyz",
                "score": "6"
            },

            {
                "annotation": "Qualification",
                "field": "EFG",
                "message": "HIJ",
                "score": "5"
            }

        }
    },
```

Now table should look like -(abc will be the parent)

```
A              B   C     D
abc            pqr  xyz   7
 jkl           pqr  xyz   6
 Qualification EFg  Hij   5
```

So, I have tried some things but no luck. Can any one please help me to solve this ? Any help will be great.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? All the data is getting printed correctly.

Comment: This is invalid json. `innerAnnotations` property should have array object.

Comment: @PankajParkar why you think so?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned wrong data in ng-repeat

ng-repeat="report in reports.data"

Replace it with 
ng-repeat="report in reports.innerAnnotations". Also you need to change the inner html angular expressions too.

Comment: But the thing is need to show the reports data as well.

Comment: Can you put your complete JSON structure? I believe you've mentioned it partially.